# Is it possible to request an APNS Device Token from the View Controler?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, push-notification

I'm new to Objective-C and iOS development, but I was wondering if there was a way to request an Apple Push Notification Device Token from the View Controller and store the token in a string to use later in a Query String sent to my web application.

I've been searching, but haven't been able to find a solution to this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` anywhere in your code.

But you'll have to implement `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` in your app delegate.

You can register for up to 3 different types of notification. Just remove and add as required.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
   registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
   (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |      //Alerts are pop up boxes or on ios5, banners
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |     //Badges are the little red number on the icon
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];    //Sounds are... well, sounds. These can be played when presenting a remote notification
```

Comment: Very similar to callbacks in smalltalk environments. The suggestion by James is sound.

Comment: That sounds right to me.  I currently have:

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: %@", deviceToken);
}

in the AppDelegate.  What would the syntax be to call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes from the View Controller?

Comment: That depends on the type of notifications you want to register for. I've added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I have registerForRemoteNotificationTypes and didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken in my app delegate.  The problem I currently have is on how to set the device token that is retrieved by didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken to a string declared in a view controller.

Comment: You have to send the token to a server so that you can use it later

Comment: The only problem I have is that I need to have the deviceToken stored in the DB and tied to the user ID.  The used currently logs into my application via a WebView.  I was wondering if it were possible to pass the token to the server in a Query String attached to the WebView URL. So far it doesn't seem like it's possible, unless you know of another way to accomplish the same thing.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: That sounds possible. Store the token to some variable when you receive it and access that variable when you want to add it to a query string